A Question about a symbol used in Weyl's Theorem in Andrew Browder's _Mathematical Analysis_
I am reading Mathematical Analysis written by Andrew Browder, and on page 170 in Section 7.4 Weyl's Theorem, theorem 7.33 says:
If $\zeta \in \mathbb{R}$ is irrational, then
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \# \{k \in \mathbb{N} : 1 \leq k \leq n, \langle k \zeta \rangle \in [a,b] \} = b-a $$
for any $0 \leq a < b < 1.$
Now my question is, what does the symbol "$\#$ " mean here in the theorem. Can somebody help explain what this symbol is and when and where to use it? Thanks!
P.S. The screenshot of Page 170 is below:


Please don't use MathJax to format text - you can bold and italicize with Markdown.

counting measure, i.e. number of elements in the set.

@Sean Thanks for your suggestion! But I am wondering what MathJax is here and when I can use it.

@Andrew Thanks! So $#$ is an abbreviation for "number of xxx"?

The symbol # literally means “number of.”

@TedShifrin Thanks!
